# With apologies to all the Elizabethan sonneteers

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I heard, O James; I beg thou 'll again share
the singular connection I first saw --
not in thine indication quite unrare,
now only when in t' after-gleam of lore.

Do tell: hast wanting heaven's lead-drawn hail?
Hail hath not all behind, or first before.
Can jousting orbs have not incursions frail?
Sleet is not good enough! Return, head sew'r.

That substance killeth e'er at such time when
a fire lord's back. Yes, thou, the last resource,
after thine heart the ultimate of ken.
Myself to Jim: at last return on course.

Imagine a decanter ringing out,
anointment! Dionysus's here! we shout.

---

Hint (added later):

> Each line is a puzzle, all fourteen of the same type.

Comment: Would you like to clarify how we should be pronouncing "sew'r" and/or whether it's meant to be an abbreviated version of "sewer" (whether that's "one who sews" or "conduit for waste water")?

Comment: (It looks as if it ought to rhyme with "before" but neither reading of "sewer" would make the vowel right for that.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, re your latter comment: but one is very close.

Comment: I assure you that neither is very close the way I pronounce them. Maybe "person who sews" is closer than "waste water pipe" but they're both miles off. Or is there some _other_ thing "sew'r" could abbreviate that would produce a different vowel sound entirely?

Comment: (Of course it may well not matter, depending on exactly what is going on in that bit of the line.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, it's from "to sew".

Comment: Thanks. FYI, I am fairly confident I understand three of the lines fairly completely; two more I'm a little doubtful about. This is not yet enough :-).

Comment: (A couple more, and the picture becomes slightly clearer. Still more holes than picture, though.)

Comment: I should have mentioned in the bounty notice that @GarethMcCaughan's idea is correct, as are his boldfaced answers and some but not all of his other specific ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea is that

> every line of the sonnet is a cryptic clue (without enumeration, alas), and when we put the answers to the clues together we get a question we need to answer.

So:

> On each line, I have "<" indicating definition on left, wordplay on right, or ">" indicating definition on right, wordplay on left.
>
> ```
> I heard, O James; > I beg thou 'll again share        WHAT
> the singular connection < I first saw --              IS
> not in thine > indication quite unrare,               THE
> now only < when in t' after-gleam of lore.            LAST
> Do tell: < hast wanting heaven's lead-drawn hail?     NAME
> Hail hath not all behind, or first before.            OF
> Can < jousting orbs have not incursions frail?        JOHN
> Sleet is not good enough! Return, head > sew'r.       SINGER
> That substance killeth < e'er at such time when       AS
> a fire lord's < back. Yes, thou, the last resource,   ZUKO
> after < thine heart the ultimate of ken.              IN
> Myself to Jim: at last return on > course.            MOTION
> Imagine < a decanter ringing out,                     PICTURE
> anointment! < Dionysus's here! we shout.              GREASE
> ```

Some explanations of things above that may not be obvious:

> Line 1: James Watt. Line 3: THINE minus IN. Line 4: AS, in T after first letter of LORE. Line 5: NAMASTE is "hail"; remove ("draw") "has wanting heaven's lead" or (-h)AST, to get NAME. Line 6: FALL (=hail) minus ALL on its right, "behind or first" = after O. "Of" means "before" as in "quarter of two" when telling time. Line 7: "incursions frail" means that we just get a little bit into each word. Line 8: initial letters; Singer is a brand of sewing machine. Line 9: arsenic. Line 10: Zuko is a Fire Lord in the animated TV series "Avatar: the last airbender". (OK U Z)<. Z is "the last resource" because it's the last letter of the alphabet. Line 12: (I TO M)< + ON.

The final answer

> would therefore be TRAVOLTA.

Credit where due:

> I didn't wholly understand some portions of the wordplay until OP kindly explained them; see comments below.

Comment: +1. You're partially right about the general trend. Do you want me to say which part?

Comment: Nah. Let's wait for Deusovi to turn up and solve it in five minutes. Or someone else. Or maybe I'll get more inspired than I expect. Anyway, no need for big hints yet, I think.

Comment: You may want to see my edit to the question.

Comment: (I have, and have drawn some conclusions therefrom, but I'm still some way short of a solution. Working on it, though.)

Comment: You got the bounty because time is running out on it and you've got most of this. Nicely done! Obviously there's more to do.

Comment: Just to confirm: all the boldfaced lines are correct (answers and explanations). Re "you might naively expect something like 'what is the last name of the ...' but then there's a word missing between 'singer' and 'as'": no, I think "What is the last name of the singer as Zuko..." is grammatical, cluing "Travolta". (Or, at least, it's as grammatical as the actual sentence I wrote.)

Comment: @msh210 - No, it's not grammatical. "singer playing Zuko" would be OK. or "singer performing as Zuko".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - Could you please add to your non-obvious explanations why 'resource' clues to 'Z'?

Comment: Sure. (But it's not "resource", it's "_the last_ resource".)

Comment: Incidentally, I agree that it isn't grammatical, but in fairness msh210 was working under quite a lot of constraints here, so some degree of "poetic" licence should be permitted.

Comment: Just sayin', I'm surprised you haven't solved the seventh line, which is easier IMO than many of the lines you did solve.

Comment: Cryptics are very difficult without letter counts or cross-checked letters. Especially when the cluing itself is a little cryptic.

Comment: @LannyStrack, yep, I'll be the first to admit this is difficult.

Comment: Seventh line has really been annoying me. It seems like it should be solvable, for sure.

Comment: Ah, I see what it is. One indicator in it seems pretty weird to me, though.

Comment: I guess maybe I now have all the pieces. But line 6 seems to be incomplete, if so.

Comment: Re your problematic line 6, I think rot13('unvy' vf 'bs' nf va 'unvy sebz', juvyr zvtug 'be svefg orsber' or pyhrvat gur svefg yrggref bs 'Be Svefg'?)

Comment: That seems just as problematic, albeit in a different way. rot13(Gur rkvfgrapr bs "unvy sebz" qbrfa'g zrna gung "unvy" zrnaf "bs", be ivpr irefn. "Unvy" vf n ireo, "bs" vf n cercbfvgvba, naq fb sne nf V pna pheeragyl guvax gurer vf ab pbagrkg va juvpu gurl ner vagrepunatrnoyr.) I do agree about rot13("be svefg orsber") being a possibility if the rest of the line fitted, though.

Comment: Not my intention, @Stiv. Re 4, rot13(n qrs bs "ynfg", ng yrnfg ng Jvxgvbanel, vf "Orvat gur bayl bar erznvavat bs vgf pynff", urapr "abj bayl"). Re 6, rot13("oruvaq be svefg" zrnaf "nsgre b" naq "orsber" vf qrs nf va "dhnegre bs gjb"). 5 is correct: well found. Re 7, rot13("vaphefvbaf senvy" zrnaf fznyy vaebnqf vagb gur jbeqf). All in all, very well done! I intended this to be difficult enough to require a multiperson brainstorm, but you pretty much got it all yourself.

Comment: Ah! rot13("dhnegre bs gjb") isn't in my idiolect though I know others use it. I'll update my answer in the light of your comments. It was a fun puzzle.

Comment: The only problem that I have with this puzzle is that rot13(vg vtaberf Genibygn'f vaperqvoyr cresbeznapr nf na NPGBE va Ternfr. ;-)). Awesome job solving it, Gareth!